# socket_create_listen not working for all interfaces in windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, sockets

I am using Symfony 4 to open a TCP listener socket. It works like a charm in linux. I have to make it working in Windows OS too.

If I execute the Symfony command, it opens the socket on 127.0.0.1:4501 and I am able to connect from a client located on the same machine. The issue occurs when I try to connect from other PC's in the LAN an other devices located outside the LAN (I have forwarded the port in the router).

This is the code to open the socket:

```
 if (!$localSocket = socket_create_listen($listeningPort)) 
 {
     throw new \RuntimeException('Could not create socket.');
 }
```

If I execute this command on a command promt, I see the port open on 127.0.0.1:4501 instead of my desired value 0.0.0.0:4501

[image: netstat -ab command]

How is possible to listen on all network interfaces and make it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got it testing with different code between Windows and Linux. This is the result:

```
//Windows
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') 
{
   $localSocket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
   socket_bind($localSocket, "0.0.0.0", $listeningPort);
   socket_listen($localSocket);
} 
else 
{
   //Linux
   if (!$localSocket = socket_create_listen($listeningPort)) 
   {
      throw new \RuntimeException('Could not create socket.');
   }
}
```